# IE 10-11, баг position:absolute

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, position

Столкнулся с проблемой верстки секции преимуществ в IE10-11. Баг со свойством `position: absolute`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В IE это выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```css
.advantages .tile {
position:relative;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
height:235px;
border-right:1px solid #e8e8e8;
border-bottom:1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.advantages .tile:hover .icon {
fill:#3fd1fa;
}
.advantages .tile:hover .tile__text-wrapper h4 {
color:#3fd1fa;
}
.advantages .tile:nth-child(4),
.advantages .tile:nth-child(8) {
border-right:0;
}
.advantages .tile:nth-child(5), 
.advantages .tile:nth-child(6),
.advantages .tile:nth-child(7),
.advantages .tile:nth-child(8) {
border-bottom:0;
}
.advantages .tile__inner {
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
width:315px;
height:235px;
transition:all .25s ease;
}
.advantages .tile:hover .tile__inner {
width:335px;
height:260px;
background-color:#fff;
box-shadow:0 0 23px 3px rgba(70,70,70,.085);
border-radius:6px;
}
.advantages .tile__icon-wrapper {
height:120px;
}
.advantages .tile__icon-wrapper .icon{
width:60px;
stroke-width:0;
fill:#8e8e8e;
transition:all .15s ease;
}
.advantages .tile__icon-wrapper .icon-direct-customer {
width:85px;
}
.advantages .tile__icon-wrapper .icon-handshake {
width:75px;
}
.advantages .tile__icon-wrapper .icon-computer-secure {
margin-top:-8px;
}
.advantages .tile__text-wrapper h4 {
color:#8b8b8b;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:400;
line-height:22px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
transition:all .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container advantages">
  <div class="row advantages__list">
    <article class="tile col-lg-3">
      <div class="tile__inner">
        <div class="tile__icon-wrapper">
          <svg class="icon icon-teamwork"><use xlink:href="img/people-page/advantages-icons/advantages-icons.svg#icon-teamwork"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tile__text-wrapper">
          <h4>Перевірені<br> роботодавці</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article><!-- /.tile col-lg-3 -->
    <article class="tile col-lg-3">
      <div class="tile__inner">
        <div class="tile__icon-wrapper">
          <svg class="icon icon-direct-customer"><use xlink:href="img/people-page/advantages-icons/advantages-icons.svg#icon-direct-customer"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tile__text-wrapper">
          <h4>Підготовка<br> до співбесіди</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article><!-- /.tile col-lg-3 -->
    <div class="tile col-lg-3">
      <div class="tile__inner">
        <div class="tile__icon-wrapper">
          <svg class="icon icon-handshake"><use xlink:href="img/people-page/advantages-icons/advantages-icons.svg#icon-handshake"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tile__text-wrapper">
          <h4>Безкоштовна допомога<br> у працевлаштуванні</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.tile col-lg-3 -->
    <article class="tile col-lg-3">
      <div class="tile__inner">
        <div class="tile__icon-wrapper">
          <svg class="icon icon-database"><use xlink:href="img/people-page/advantages-icons/advantages-icons.svg#icon-database"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tile__text-wrapper">
          <h4>Онлайн-реєстрація<br> в базі</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article><!-- /.tile col-lg-3 -->
    <article class="tile col-lg-3">
      <div class="tile__inner">
        <div class="tile__icon-wrapper">
          <svg class="icon icon-graphic"><use xlink:href="img/people-page/advantages-icons/advantages-icons.svg#icon-graphic"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tile__text-wrapper">
          <h4>SWOT-аналіз<br> кар’єри</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article><!-- /.tile col-lg-3 -->
    <article class="tile col-lg-3">
      <div class="tile__inner">
        <div class="tile__icon-wrapper">
          <svg class="icon icon-financial"><use xlink:href="img/people-page/advantages-icons/advantages-icons.svg#icon-financial"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tile__text-wrapper">
          <h4>Планування<br> кар’єри</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article><!-- /.tile col-lg-3 -->
    <article class="tile col-lg-3">
      <div class="tile__inner">
        <div class="tile__icon-wrapper">
          <svg class="icon icon-computer-secure"><use xlink:href="img/people-page/advantages-icons/advantages-icons.svg#icon-computer-secure"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tile__text-wrapper">
          <h4>Конфіденційність</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article><!-- /.tile col-lg-3 -->
    <article class="tile col-lg-3">
      <div class="tile__inner">
        <div class="tile__icon-wrapper">
          <svg class="icon icon-quality"><use xlink:href="img/people-page/advantages-icons/advantages-icons.svg#icon-quality"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tile__text-wrapper">
          <h4>6 років<br> на ринку</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article><!-- /.tile col-lg-3 -->
  </div><!-- /.row advantages__list -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Какие могут быть проблемы или как их обойти?

Comment: Нужно обязательно указывать относительно каких сторон происходит инициализация позиционирования. Например, top: 0; left: 0. Если Хром умеет игнорировать это и ставить по дефолту значение выше, то ИЕ и другие знакомые браузеры этого не делают.

Comment: @NeedHate Это понятно, я это уже сделал. Но анимация не та. Или убрать для IE или смириться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставлю это как идею:
Вместо увеличения размеров контейнера, можно использовать псевдоэлемент, который и будет выполнять функцию визуализации наведения на блок. Как анимация расширения блока будет использовать трансформация с параметром scale. Трансформация лучше работает с FPS, чем динамическое увеличение ширины/высоты.
Работает в IE11:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.grid > .item {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  flex: 1 1 24%;
  border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  height: 200px;
}
.grid > .item .inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid > .item .inner:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: white;
  transition: .3s;
}
.grid > .item .inner span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.grid > .item:hover .inner:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}
.grid > .item:nth-child(4), .grid > .item:nth-child(8) {
  border-right: 0;
}
.grid > .item:nth-child(5), .grid > .item:nth-child(6), .grid > .item:nth-child(7), .grid > .item:nth-child(8) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="inner"><span>Some text #1</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="inner"><span>Some text #2</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="inner"><span>Some text #3</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="inner"><span>Some text #4</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="inner"><span>Some text #5</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="inner"><span>Some text #6</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="inner"><span>Some text #7</span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="inner"><span>Some text #8</span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я игрался с псевдоэлементом. Но мне было лень по-моему добавить дополнительную обертку для контенту с текстом и иконкой :)))
Но спасибо за код =)
Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Решил, кстати, дополнительный стилем для IE10+ `_:-ms-lang(x), .class {properties}`